# Mass of each planet?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I would like to know which one makes more sense.

> The **mass** of each planet was subtracted to find the...
>
> The **masses** of each planet were subtracted to find the...

The second one sounds better to me, but I know that masses of each planet does not make much sense, as there cannot be multiple masses that coexist for a planet. However, the first one does not appeal to me any more than the second, as handling the matter of subtraction requires two entities, but the sentence only gives a singular noun, the mass of each planet (or is it considered plural?). I would like to know which one makes more sense, and why.

Answer (score 1):

These are you main choices:

The total mass of the planets was subtracted [from something] ...

The mass of each planet was subtracted from  [from something]...

The combined mass of the planets was subtracted  [from something]...

**each** implies an iterative process.

In your sentence, the [something] could be part of a preceding context if it is not explicitly supplied by your sentence.

Comment: I want to convey the meaning that all of these masses were from each other, not from a singular entity.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  Subtraction is not a reciprocal process.

Comment: Well I mean in the sense of if there were planet 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, 1 needs to be subtracted from 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, and 2 needs to be subtracted from 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, and so on.

Comment: I've downvoted your question because you have really failed to make clear what it is you're trying to say here. This is hardly a question about whether to use a plural or a singular.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence might read

> The **mass** of each planet was subtracted from *each other* planet's mass.
>   *Each planet's mass was subtracted from the other planets.*

meaning every permutation of mass subtraction was done.

Comment: Thank you! But wouldn't you consider this sentence a little stilted?

Comment: That's why the alternative underneath in *italics*, both have the same meaning.